# Discord.py rewrite : InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <class 'str'>, of type: <class 'type'>

Tags: discord, discord.py

I was following a video on how to use the craiyon module, but i followed the tutorial and it just gave me errors:

Errors:
InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <class 'str'>, of type: <class 'type'>

My code:

```
@slashFun.command(name = "art", description = "Generate Images")
async def art(interaction : discord.Interaction, prompt : str):
    logCommand("/fun art", interaction.user, interaction.guild, params={"prompt":str})
    ETA = int(time.time() + 60)
    msg = await interaction.response.send_message(f"Go get some coffee! This might take some time (ETA: <t:{ETA}:R>)")
    generator = Craiyon()
    result = generator.generate(prompt)
    images = result.images
    for i in images:
        image = BytesIO(base64.decodebytes(i.encode("utf-8")))
        return await interaction.edit_original_response(content = "Content Generated by **craiyon.com**", file=discord.File(image, "genedimage.png"))
```

Comment: Please provide where the said error occurs. Paste the entire traceback

Comment: New error: InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <class 'str'>, of type: <class 'type'>

Comment: thats the entire traceback

Comment: Can you link the tutorial? I have no clue what the craiyon library is supposed to do. What the function calls in your code generate or anything. 

Based on the variable names that you have provided, it seems like the problem might be with the fact that you are trying to encode an image in utf-8 format instead of base64 or something.